# What modules should I look at for doing multithreading in Perl?

Tags: perl, multithreading

What modules should I look at for doing multithreading in Perl?

I'm looking to do something fairly low performance; I want threads is to run multiple workers simultaneously, with each of them sleeping for varying amounts of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most recent versions of Perl have threading support. Run `perl -V:usethreads` to see if it is available in your system.

```
$ perl -V:usethreads
usethreads='define'
```

[`perldoc threads`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/threads) gives a pretty good introduction to using them.

Answer (score 9):

There are lots of reasons why you might not want to multithread. If you do want to multithread, however, the following code might serve as a helpful example. It creates a number of jobs, puts those in a thread-safe queue, then starts some threads that pull jobs from the queue and complete them. Each thread keeps pulling jobs from the queue in a loop until it sees no more jobs. The program waits for all the thread to finish and then prints the total time that it spent working on the jobs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use Modern::Perl;

my $queue= Thread::Queue->new;
my $thread_count= 4;
my $job_count= 10;
my $start_time= time;
my $max_job_time= 10;

# Come up with some jobs and put them in a thread-safe queue. Each job
# is a string with an id and a number of seconds to sleep. Jobs consist
# of sleeping for the specified number of seconds.
my @jobs= map {"$_," . (int(rand $max_job_time) + 1)} (1 .. $job_count);
$queue->enqueue(@jobs);

# List the jobs
say "Jobs IDs: ", join(", ", map {(split /,/, $_)[0]} @jobs);

# Start the threads
my @threads= map {threads->create(sub {function($_)})} (1 .. $thread_count);

# Wait for all the threads to complete their work
$_->join for (@threads);

# We're all done
say "All done! Total time: ", time - $start_time;

# Here's what each thread does. Each thread starts, then fetches jobs
# from the job queue until there are no more jobs in the queue. Then,
# the thread exists.
sub function {
  my $thread_id= shift;
  my ($job, $job_id, $seconds);
  while($job= $queue->dequeue_nb) {
    ($job_id, $seconds)= split /,/, $job;
    say "Thread $thread_id starting on job $job_id ",
      "(job will take $seconds seconds).";
    sleep $seconds;
    say "Thread $thread_id done with job $job_id.";
  }
  say "No more jobs for thread $thread_id; thread exiting.";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If performance isn't a big issue, then `fork`ing multiple processes will probably be a lot easier than dealing with threads. I frequently use [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager) which is very simple, but very good at what it does.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you don't need preemptive multithreading; in which case, look at [POE](http://poe.perl.org/?What_POE_Is)'s cooperative model. Since your code will only yield to other threads when you decide, and you'll only have one thread running at a time, development and debugging will be much easier.

Comment: Worth noting is that while POE doesn't implicitly support multithreading or multiprocessing, `POE::Wheel::Run` lets you run a piece of code in a forked process, translating its I/O and exit status into POE events. Sometimes it's a very useful thing to wrap around blocking code.

Comment: I second that                                   _

Answer (score 2):

[Coro](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Coro) is a nice module for cooperative multitasking.

99% of the time, this is what you need if you want threads in Perl.

If you want threads to speed up your code when multiple cores are available, you are going down the wrong path.  Perl is 50x slower than other languages.  Rewriting your code to run on two CPUs means that it now only runs 25x slower than other languages ... on one CPU.  Better to spend the effort porting the slow parts to a different language.

But if you just don't want IO to block other "threads", then Coro is exactly what you want.

Comment: There is also development speed.

Comment: I am tired of this argument :) There are many things I can hack together as quickly in Haskell as in Perl, and Haskell runs much faster than perl.

Comment: I agree with parts of this, but claiming that Perl is 50x slower than other languages is an exaggeration that only applies to certain operations. As you know, Perl's IO and regular expressions are on par with the best compiled languages. If a programmer can identify bottlenecks and has the developer time, it may be worth writing some code in a DSL using Inline::C. If they have to rewrite the majority of their code in the DSL to get good performance speed-ups, then it might make sense to drop Perl entirely.

Comment: Maybe that's true for some workloads, but in my experience (limited though it is), it's not. Perl's digest modules are at worst 10% slower than their native executable counterparts, so if you're doing file data processing with digests, you'll get a linear performance boost with the number of cores. In more general cases, the slowest parts of the program may already be written with XS, so rewriting in C wouldn't be the great optimization you're claiming anyway.