# What are the alternatives to Perl interpreter threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl

[perldoc threads](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads) says:

> The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged.

Are there any other Perl based threads? Or should we just not use threads in Perl?

Comment: The answer depends on why you think you need threads.

Comment: Related: [Use cases for ithreads (interpreter threads) in Perl and rationale for using or not using them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9973860/176646)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. I still use threads extensively, and there isn't a massive problem with them.

The biggest problem with them is that they are not lightweight, where if you've threaded in other languages, you might expect them to be.

They're more the opposite - spawning a thread is like starting your code again, but with some useful hooks for IPC. That means you really don't want to be doing a task-per-thread model of program, like you might be thinking of.

Instead, you would be much better served by a `Thread::Queue` worker-thread style model. Here's an example of that:
[Perl daemonize with child daemons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296206/perl-daemonize-with-child-daemons/26297240#26297240)

However, you *may* want to consider using `fork` as an alternative. `fork` - because of it's implementation on Unix - is a very efficient system call, and can be quite efficient for spawning new processes. 
The downside is - it's not quite as friendly for doing IPC.

`Parallel::ForkManager` is one module that I like for doing forking for multiprocessing.

But in either case you should note - multiprocessing isn't a magic bullet. It lets you hog more CPUs *if* you have the right sort of problem to solve. It won't make your disks go any faster :)

Answer (score 7):

That warning is poppycock. It should be removed. The developers of Perl explained that it means "The use of interpreter-based threads in perl is officially discouraged *if you want a lightweight system for multitasking*".

Since creating new threads can be expensive, just use a model that involves reusable worker threads.

Comment: Indeed. The biggest "flaw" I've found is the assumption that they're lightweight, like they are in some other languages.

Answer (score 1):

As long as I know, there are not any reliable thread implemantations. You should stick to some event-based modules, like [Coro](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MLEHMANN/Coro-6.42/Coro.pm), [AnyEvent](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent), [IO::Async](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async) etc.

Comment: Just cause the docs aren't clear, Coro is a co-operative multi-tasking system. If you want to use threads to split CPU load across cores, it's not going to help. Any neither are event-based systems. They're useful when most tasks are spent waiting on external events.

Comment: Perl threads are perfectly reliable. They're just not a _light weight_ thread that you might expect if you've come from another language.

Comment: Alas, Coro and AnyEvent are not supported since perl 5.22.